# Attribute Error : Function object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I see there are so many questions about this title or for this issue, But I still don't understand why it is occurring.

I have imported Pandas and Numpy. 
Then I read my file using pd.read_excel. 
Then I viewed the head of my file using .head()
Now, after I sliced my data also the .head method was working fine. But now suddenly it throws an Attribute error and it gets resolved once I re-import my file again, but then, after some time it again gives me the same error. What is wrong that I am doing? and I don't understand this error clearly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sales = pd.read_excel('SALESC.xlsx', header=0)
sales.isnull().sum()
sales["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(sales['Date of document'])
sales = sales[pd.notnull(sales['Quantity sold']) & pd.notnull(sales['Unit     
        selling price including tax'])]
sales = sales.iloc[:,[3,6,8,9,10,11,19,35,39]]

sales.head(5)
```

[image: Attribute Error]

Can someone explain the problem? and how to resolve it, thanks in advance

Comment: Restart your kernel.

Comment: I tried the same code in Atom Python 3 IDE and also in Spyder, it the same in both. Would just restarting my kernel will solve the problem?

Comment: remove the `read_excel` portion of this and build your dataframe by hand with some hard coded values. that way, other people can run this code and help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is because you're trying to access the `shape` attribute of the `df.dropna` function, instead of accessing the `shape` attribute of the DataFrame `df`. This happens when you forget to include the parentheses `()` when invoking the `dropna` function, causing Python to treat `df.dropna` as a function object rather than as a DataFrame.

To resolve this issue, make sure you're calling the `dropna` function correctly by using the parentheses `()` at the end. Here's the corrected code in English:

```py
# Call the dropna function to remove rows with missing values
df = df.dropna()

# After removing rows with missing values, you can check the size of the DataFrame
print(df.shape)
```

Make sure to use parentheses when calling functions in Python, as it is essential for executing the function and accessing its results. The error should disappear once you correct this omission.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35202357)